# What is the HP of gauntlets?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, equipment

What is the HP of a pair of [medium gauntlets](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/gauntlet)?

Under the [damaging objects rules](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/damaging-objects/) where this information should be listed, it seems to be missing.

Bladed, ranged, and shafted weapons are listed, but gauntlets are different.

Answer (score 3):

Based on https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/damaging-objects/ I would estimate that a pair of steel gauntlets would have 10 hardness (+2 per "plus" of enhancement that the gauntlets have).

For HP my estimate would be 10, based on the 10 HP that a light steel shield or a pair of manacles has (both at the same URL). Again, if the gauntlets are magical I would follow the guideline that each "plus" of enhancement provided by the gauntlets provides an additional 10 HP.

Comment: Since gauntlets are generally a weapon and not armor, why are you using armor?

Comment: @Fering Actually, although gauntlets are USED as weapons, they are actually part of two thirds of the available armours - either method would make equal sense.